# How to use InputHandler when dragging a marker on Google Maps in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I have added this marker successfully on a Google Map:

```
Marker(
    state = MarkerState(
        position = LatLng(lat, lng)
    ),
    title = "Party",
    snippet = "Come to party.",
    draggable = true
)
```

I set it to be draggable. Now I want to know when someone is dragging it. I found this function called [InputHandler()](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-input-handler.html) but I have no idea how to use it.

I tried using:

```
InputHandler(
    onMarkerDragEnd = { marker ->
        Log.d(TAG, "${marker.id}")
    }
)
```

But nothing happens. Can anyone help? Or any other idea for knowing when a marker is dragged?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the OnMarkerDragListener interface to listen for marker drag events.

```
val marker = googleMap.addMarker(
    MarkerOptions()
        .position(LatLng(lat, lng))
        .title("Location")
        .snippet("set Location.")
        .draggable(true)
)

googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(object : OnMarkerDragListener {
    override fun onMarkerDragStart(marker: Marker?) {
        // Called when marker drag starts
    }

    override fun onMarkerDrag(marker: Marker?) {
        // Called while marker is being dragged
    }

    override fun onMarkerDragEnd(marker: Marker?) {
        // Called when marker drag ends
        Log.d(TAG, "${marker?.id}")
    }
})
```

here is For **maps-compose** library

```
 var markerPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194)) }
var isDragging by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target = markerPosition, zoom = 10f),
    onMapClick = { /* handle map clicks */ }
) { map ->
    if (isDragging) {
        // While dragging, create a temporary marker with opacity set to 0
        Marker(
            position = markerPosition,
            alpha = 0f
        )
    } else {
        // When not dragging, create a visible marker
        Marker(
            position = markerPosition,
            title = "Party",
            snippet = "Come to party.",
            draggable = true,
            onClick = { /* handle marker clicks */ }
        )
    }
}

// Listen for drag events using the pointer input system
PointerInput(Unit) {
    forEachGesture {
        awaitPointerEventScope {
            val down = awaitFirstDown()
            if (down.changes.any { it.changedToDown() && it.position in markerPosition.toOffset() }) {
                // If the user starts a drag gesture on the marker, set isDragging to true
                isDragging = true
            }

            val up = awaitUpOrCancellation()
            if (up.changes.any { it.changedToUp() }) {
                // If the user stops a drag gesture, set isDragging to false and update the marker position
                isDragging = false
                markerPosition = up.changes.first { it.changedToUp() }.position.toLatLng()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not available anymore. I'm using [Maps Compose Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose).

Comment: @JoanP. you can use the Modifier.draggable modifier to make a marker draggable, and then add a callback using the onDragEnd parameter to listen for drag events

Comment: I don't think that it will work. The [Marker](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-marker.html) composable doesn't have a Modifier. See?

Comment: The [Marker](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-marker.html) composable doesn't have an `onDragEnd` either.

Comment: Where does this PointerInput come from?